# How to append next dict within array

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm building the dict by fetching values from the devices. 
I would like keep adding new dict into "c" by appending a new item. 
How can to append new dict within array:

```
dict1 = {
'a': 1,
'b': 2,
'c': [{'aa': 11, 'bb': 22}]}
newvalue = {'aa': 111, 'bb': 222}
dict1['c'] = dict1['c'] + newvalue

End results:
dict1 = {
'a': 1,
'b': 2,
'c': [{'aa': 11, 'bb': 22},{'aa': 111, 'bb': 222}}
```

How to append using forloop?

Comment: `dict1['c'].append(newvalue)`…?

Comment: What you're doing already works. If you make a bunch of `newvalue` values inside a `for` loop, you can just use the exact same code you already have to add each of those values.

Comment: would like to add newvalues into dict['c'], how can i append the newvalue

Comment: doesn't work. here i code I tired:
```for k, v in dict1['c'][0].iteritems():
  dict1['c'].append(v)
  print dict1```

Answer (score 2):

The trick to this question is understanding your object types.

Let's try finding the type of `dict1['c']`, as this is the one we're trying to add to:

```
print(type(dict1['c']))
<class 'list'>
```

While we're at it let's see what's inside this list:

```
print(type(dict1['c'][0]))
<class 'dict'>
```

So we have a list, and the first element of the list is a dictionary.

It looks like we want to add another dictionary to this list. But, wait, is the fact we're adding a *dictionary* at all relevant? Probably not, we know `list` can contain any number of objects.

So let's see how we can add to a list. A quick google gives us [**Difference between append vs. extend list methods in Python**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/252703/difference-between-append-vs-extend-list-methods-in-python). So we need `list.append`. Let's try that:

```
dict1['c'].append(newvalue)

print(dict1)

{'a': 1,
 'b': 2,
 'c': [{'aa': 11, 'bb': 22},
       {'aa': 111, 'bb': 222}]}
```

Hey, presto! That's *exactly* what we were looking for.

Comment: Thank you JPP it was good: Question: 
for example: within a forloop I found a value and need to add to key: "aa", so I did >> `dict1['c'][0]["aa"] = 333`  and `dict1['c'][0]["bb"] = 444`
Now how to add those two into conituing array of dict?

Comment: @netkool, Sorry, it's not clear what you are doing. In your comment, you are **changing the value for dictionary keys** (specifically first dictionary) for keys `aa` and `bb` respectively. This has **nothing** to do with adding elements.

Answer (score 0):

And to elaborate on jpp's superior answer, it does work in a for loop (the code below would usually have an index instead of simply 'newvalue').

```
newvalue = {'aa': 111, 'bb': 222}

dict1 = {
'a': 1,
'b': 2,
'c': [{'aa': 11, 'bb': 22}]}

for i in range(1):
    dict1['c'].append(newvalue)
print(dict1)
```

**Result:**

```
{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': [{'aa': 11, 'bb': 22}, {'aa': 111, 'bb': 222}]}
```